# Flutter firebase_messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to handle firebase_messaging in my Flutter test project.
What I've done.
1. Created simple Flutter project.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging(); // For FCM
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(); // To be used as navigator

  String _message;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /* Handle Notifications */
    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onMessage: $message");
        setState(() {
          _message = message.toString();
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onLaunch: $message");
        setState(() {
          _message = message.toString();
        });
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        debugPrint("onResume: $message");
        setState(() {
          _message = message.toString();
        });
      },
    );

    _fcm.getToken().then((String token) {
      debugPrint("token: $token");
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Firebase messages"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Text(_message == null ? "NO MESSAGE YET" : _message,),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

5. Registered project in Firebase console in order to reseive messages.
6. Sent message from Firebase console when my app in active state (in foreground). It works perfect - I can see debug message

```
onMessage: {notification: {title: My title, body: My message body}, data: {}}
```

7. Send message from Firebase console when my app in background. I could see Firebase notification. But when I click on it my application returned to active state (back to foreground) and no debug message

```
onResume: {notification: {title: My title, body: My message body}, data: {}}
```

Could you suggest me where is my fault?
What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firebase_messaging` needs some more configurations and doing some extra work in the firebase console when sending the message.

In "Other options" in the firebase console, you need to add a new key-value pair like this:

```
"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
```

Then, you need to tell your app to handle notifications with this `click_action` in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And that should be it, now your app will be able to handle the notification click and trigger `onResume`!

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you very much Francisco. I've done what you suggested. Now I have onResume event firing. But I get empty message. For example ```onResume: {notification: {}, data: {collapse_key: ru.alexeyzhulin.firebasemessages, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1588142576210, google.delivered_priority: high, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 40921386609, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:1588142576213008%03eb999a03eb999a}}``` Could you suggest me how to get message content

Comment: Sure, just add two key-value pair into the data tag with title and message of the notification (again). Android (for whatever reason) destroy what is inside of the notification, so you need to backup the data.

Comment: Got it. Thank you a lot :)